# Transfer an email with Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I've tried with no conclusions to resend emails with Python.

Once I've logged in SMTP and IMAP with TLS, this is what I have written:

```
status, data = self._imapserver.fetch(id, "(RFC822)")
email_data = data[0][1]

# create a Message instance from the email data
message = email.message_from_string(email_data)

# replace headers (could do other processing here)
message.replace_header("From", 'blablabla@bliblibli.com')
message.replace_header("To", 'blobloblo@blublublu.com')

self._smtpserver.sendmail('blablabla@bliblibli.com', 'blobloblo@blublublu.com', message.as_string())
```

But the problem is that the variable data doesn't catch the information from the email, even if the ID is the one I need.
It tells me:

```
b'The specified message set is invalid.'
```

How can I transfer an email with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, whatever you have in `id` is invalid. We don't know what you put there, so all we can tell you is what's already in the error message.

(Also, probably don't use `id` as a variable name, as you will shadow the built-in function with the same name.)

There are additional bugs further on in your code; you need to use `message_from_bytes` if you want to parse it, though there is really no need to replace the headers just to resend it.

```
status, data = self._imapserver.fetch(correct_id, "(RFC822)")
self._smtpserver.sendmail('blablabla@bliblibli.com', 'blobloblo@blublublu.com', data[0][1])
```

If you want to parse the message, you should perhaps add a `policy` argument; this selects the modern `EmailMessage` API which was introduced in Python 3.6.

```
from email.policy import default
...
message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=default)
message["From"] = "blablabla@bliblibli.com"
message["To"] = "blobloblo@blublublu.com"
self._smtpserver.send_message(message)
```

The `send_message` method is an addition to the new API. If the message could contain other recipient headers like `Cc:`, `Bcc:` etc, perhaps using the good old `sendmail` method would be better, as it ignores the message's headers entirely.